# How to make a clickable button (image changing when clicked) in an html displayed by android and iphone webviews

Tags: android, image, button, webview, click

I have a webapp for android and iphone that uses a webview to display a web page.
The page contains a graphic button implemented this way:

```
<INPUT id="OkBorder" type="image" src="ok_off.png"  border="0"  onclick="OkClicked()">
```

I would like users to see a click effect (image on button changes to ok_on.png then back again to ok_off.png) just before redirecting them to a new page.

I tried to use :

```
function OkClicked() 
{
   button = document.getElementById("OkBorder");
   button.src = "ok_on.png";
}
```

but i don't see the image change when i click it...

Is there a way to show a button click effect this way in a webview ?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think `button.src` is right because the `src` is not a javasript command. Is [this](http://gwydir.demon.co.uk/jo/javascript/pix.htm) what you wanted to do, if not then you might want to try d. Other sites seem to use hidden and visable which you might want to try.